# Scheduled Jitterbit Upsert

Tags: data-loader, jitterbit

I have a couple different upserts built out in Jitterbit that are all supposed to be running nightly. Some of them are working and some of them are not. As far as I can tell they are set up the exact same just with different data and I cannot figure out why some are working and some are not. I scheduled them all at different times throughout the night so that they won't be stepping on each other but still no luck.

Has anyone seen this before and can offerup any suggestions?

Chad